# javascript - another function scope multiple .js file question

Tags: javascript, function, scope, typeerror

I have 2 `.js` files.  Included, in order  `library.js`   followed by `other.js`. When calling the logger function as shown below from inside `abc`, I get  `Uncaught TypeError: logger is not a function`.

`logger` can be found and called from outside abc in the `other.js` script so I know it is loaded. How can I call `logger` from inside `abc` (to avoid code duplication) ?  I thought `logger.js` would be in global scope and accessible from everywhere.

### library.js

```
var logger = function(param){
  //...
  console.log(param);
 // ...
}

logger("library.js is included");
```

### other.js

```
var x = 0;
logger("I am other"); // this happens!
var abc = {
    showDebug : true,
    doStuff : function(){
    //...
    if(this.showDebug){
        logger("Debugging now"); // this errors
    }
    // ...
  }
}
abc.doStuff();
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure the error is thrown from that line specifically? If so, what is the error?

Comment: I tried it local and it is working. [![Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r50K.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r50K.png) The HTML has this order: <script src="library.js"​></script>​ <script src="other.js"​></script>​

Comment: Thanks for checking guys.  I did summarise my code so I will see if I can post the full scripts. If I put the logger function at the top of other.js  it works in both locations with no errors.  Once in an external file it won't work inside 'abc'

Comment: actually - running my abbreviated version DOES work....doh

Comment: Sorry everyone  - I had accidently done a logger = rather than a logger() somewhere else.  My bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is accessible, works fine. Maybe inside of `doStuff` method you are reassigning something else to `logger` variable.

```js
const logger = string => console.log(string)

logger('works')

var abc = {
    showDebug : true,
    doStuff : function(){
      if(this.showDebug){
          logger("Debugging now");
      }
    }
}

abc.doStuff();
```

Comment: Cheers for looking at this:  If I put the logger function at the top of other.js it works in both locations with no errors. Once in an external file it won't work inside 'abc'

Comment: You were right - I had reassigned it by accident.  Should have showed the full script.